# Choose column 'row' value based on row value in panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a data frame with multiple rows like this:

```
N  amount country codeA codeB
0  -15678   NAN    CH    US
1  3475     NAN    POL   FR
```

How can I select column codeA for the value of country when the amount is negative and codeB when positive

I would like to have something like this as output

```
N  amount country codeA codeB
0  -15678   CH    CH    US
1  3475     FR    POL   FR
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `np.where`:

```py
df['country'] = np.where(df['amount'] < 0, df['codeA'], df['codeB'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   N  amount country codeA codeB
0  0  -15678      CH    CH    US
1  1    3475      FR   POL    FR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method along with a lambda function in pandas. :

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
data = {
    'N': [0, 1],
    'amount': [-15678, 3475],
    'country': ['NAN', 'NAN'],
    'codeA': ['CH', 'POL'],
    'codeB': ['US', 'FR']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Apply lambda function to select codeA or codeB based on the amount value
df['country'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['codeA'] if row['amount'] < 0 else row['codeB'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   N  amount country codeA codeB
0  0  -15678      CH    CH    US
1  1    3475      FR   POL    FR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to calculate `country` value for each row and then apply it to the DataFrame row-by-row with `.apply()` method. `axis=1` means that the fucntion is applied to each row (as opposed to each column).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "N": [0, 1],
    "amount": [-15678, 3475],
    "codeA": ["CH", "POL"],
    "codeB": ["US", "FR"]
})

def get_country(row):
    return row["codeA"] if row["amount"] < 0 else row["codeB"]

df["country"] = df.apply(get_country, axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
    N       amount  codeA   codeB   country
0   0       -15678  CH      US      CH
1   1       3475    POL     FR      FR
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this below code

```
df['country'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['codeA'] if x['amount'] < 0 else x['codeB'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the apply function along with a lambda function in pandas.
try this below code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
data = {'N': [0, 1],
        'amount': [-15678, 3475],
        'country': ['NAN', 'NAN'],
        'codeA': ['CH', 'POL'],
        'codeB': ['US', 'FR']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a function to select the appropriate column based on the amount value
def select_column(row):
    if row['amount'] < 0:
        return row['codeA']
    else:
        return row['codeB']

# Apply the function to create a new column with the selected code
df['selected_code'] = df.apply(lambda row: select_column(row), axis=1)

# Update the 'country' column based on the selected code
df['country'] = df['selected_code']

# Drop the 'selected_code' column if not needed
df.drop('selected_code', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```